# How to fix broken `msgfmt` installation?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, gettext, msgfmt

Several projects that I am trying to build from scratch appear to need `msgfmt` in order to build.  They all fail.

However, when I try to run it directly on the command line I get:

```
$ msgfmt
msgfmt: error while loading shared libraries: libgettextsrc-0.18.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have `gettext` installed, but it seems to be 0.18.3 instead of 0.18.1:

> ii  gettext                                     0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3                    amd64        GNU Internationalization utilities
>   ii  gettext-base                                0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3

Ubuntu version is:

> lsb_release -a
>
> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
>
> Description:   Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
>
> Release:   14.04
>
> Codename:  trusty

---

Edit:

```
$ apt-cache policy gettext
gettext:
   Installed: 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3
   Candidate: 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3
   Version table:
    *** 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 0
   500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
   100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   0.18.3.1-1ubuntu2 0
   500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

And then

```
$ ls -la $(which msgfmt)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 79104 Jul 13 09:14 /opt/bitnami/common/bin/msgfmt
```

Comment: `ls /usr/bin/msgfmt` gives `/usr/bin/msgfmt`?

Comment: Yes, it does. Ah! That sounds suspicious.... Hmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right `gettext` package installed, but your PATH is a bit inconvenient and therefore you use the "wrong" `msgfmt`.

---

The path `/opt/bitnami/common/bin` should be after `/usr/bin` and so on. Place `/opt/bitnami/common/bin` at the end of your PATH settings.